# how to find distinct elements in a 2d array

Tags: c++

can anyone suggest me a faster method of finding number of distinct elements in a 2-d matrix whose staring and ending position is given.. (matrix elements are less than 20)
say matrix is ...

```
     1 2 3
     4 5 6 
     4 2 1
```

starting point(1,1)..ending (3,2) then ans will b 4.. i.e 1,2,4,5..
following approach seems to b quite slow..

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
main()
{
    int n,a[301][301],b[12],count,x1,x2,y1,y2,i,j;
    unsigned long long q;
    cin>>n;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            cin>>a[i][j];
    cin>>q;
    while(q--)
        {
            count=0;
            for(i=0;i<12;i++)
                b[i]=0;
            cin>>x1>>y1>>x2>>y2;
            for(i=x1-1;i<=x2-1;i++)
                for(j=y1-1;j<=y2-1;j++)
                    b[a[i][j]]++;
            for(i=0;i<12;i++)
                {
                    if(b[i])
                        count++;
                }
            cout<<count<<"\n";
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Get in the habit of always putting braces around the bodies of loops and if. You'll thank me someday.

Comment: @Barmar - Braces are a good idea. Prevents getting caught with your trousers around your ankles.

Comment: will doing this question with some other data structure...(excpt 1or 2d arrays) b faster..

Comment: Why do you think this code is slow?

Comment: Instead of the `b` array you could use a `std::set`.

Comment: But as long as the size of `b` is small, I don't think it really matters.

Comment: i m nt sure .. but jus wanna know if it could b done fastr with some other data structure..

Comment: how to use set in this ques.. actually i m new to c++...:P

Comment: tell me how to use  vector<bool> to serve my purpose...

Comment: is it possibl to reduce the complexity to O(1) any how using memoisation... ??